# Multi-Project support on Opengrok issue

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, opengrok

I create 2 opengrok project on the server following the instruction in [How-to-install-OpenGrok](https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/wiki/How-to-install-OpenGrok).

Each project have its own name: project1 and project 2.

After I create the index, deploy my projects and restart my tomcat. Only the first project that I viewed on browser works. The other project will prompt error:

> HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class org.opensolaris.opengrok.analysis.AnalyzerGuru
>
> type Exception report
>
> message org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class org.opensolaris.opengrok.analysis.AnalyzerGuru
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class org.opensolaris.opengrok.analysis.AnalyzerGuru
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:555)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:401)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:345)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.opensolaris.opengrok.web.StatisticsFilter.doFilter(StatisticsFilter.java:55)
>     org.opensolaris.opengrok.web.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:66)

For example: If I view Project 1 first, Project 2 will prompt error. The only way to make Project 2 work is to restart tomcat and view project 2 first.

The version of OpenGrok that I'm using is V1.0. Tomcat version 8.

Command that I use to create index is list below:

```
OPENGROK_VERBOSE=true OPENGROK_WEBAPP_CONTEXT=${webapp name} OPENGROK_INSTANCE_BASE=${path_to_store_index_files} ./OpenGrok index ${directory_of_source_code}
```

Comment: URL that I use to view these two project is different. One using localhost:8080/project1, the other using localhost:8080/project2

Answer (score 0):

if jdk is oracle one 1.8 , then this looks like a bug - feel free to open one on 
https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/issues

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with the second OpenGrok (1.1 rc11) instance on Tomcat8 on Ubuntu 16.04.

It looks like an insufficient memory problem.
I tried below steps and the problem disappeared.

1. Set a larger heap size for Tomcat8 in file /etc/default/tomcat8. Here it's set to 8g. (There is total 32GB RAM on my machine)

   JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true **-Xmx8g** -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
2. Restart the tomcat8 service

   sudo service tomcat8 restart

Hope above help.